# Display rows from database in html table using jQuery, Ajax, json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I need some help with the following code. I am trying to query my database using ajax and return the results within a table. The code is executing and I am not getting any errors - I'm just not getting a response. Any ideas? I have a feeling something is messed up with my jQuery function.

Thanks for any help you can give.

My function in my view:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    var form_data = {
        Opportunity_Id: $('#Opportunity_Id').val(),
        ajax: '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/get_classes'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(server_response) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                week = data[i];
                $("table.table").append("<tr><td>" + week.Class_Number + "</td><td>" + week.Class_Date + "</td></tr>");
            };
        },
        error: function(thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

My controller:

```
function get_classes() {
    $Opportunity_Id = $this->input->post('Opportunity_Id');
    $this->ion_auth_model->get_classes($Opportunity_Id);

    foreach ($classes as $class):
        $results[] = array(
                        "Class_Number" => $class->Class_Number,
                        "Class_Date" => $class->Class_Date,
                        "Start_Time" => $class->Start_Time,
                        "End_Time" => $class->End_Time
                    );
    endforeach;

    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

My model:

```
function get_classes($Opportunity_Id) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('Classes')->where('Opportunity_Id', $Opportunity_Id);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($q->result() as $classes) {
            $data[] = $classes;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your data variable looks like in ajax response?

Comment: try firebug or chrome debugger to check what response you get or error you receive.

Comment: @RonakPatel I'm not sure I understand. I see the code is executing by looking at the network log within my browser dev tools. Within my view, the rows are not populating within my table.

Comment: @Zeeshan I am getting the following error in the console - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: @user1337595 at which line are you getting this syntax error? and why don't you mention it in your question?

Comment: @user1337595 Is it showing only that and which file it is suggesting.The filename will be shown to right of error you are getting in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this maybe your problem, you are returning an array from `get_classes($Opportunity_Id)` but you have not captured that array when you call it :-

```
function get_classes() {
    $Opportunity_Id = $this->input->post('Opportunity_Id');
    $classes = $this->ion_auth_model->get_classes($Opportunity_Id);   <--- changed here

    foreach ($classes as $class):
        $results[] = array(
                        "Class_Number" => $class->Class_Number,
                        "Class_Date" => $class->Class_Date,
                        "Start_Time" => $class->Start_Time,
                        "End_Time" => $class->End_Time
                    );
    endforeach;

    echo json_encode($results);
}
```